# Preventing file access in apache and not showing their existance

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to block few files and folders from direct access on apache. Looking at a few answers here I have done the following:

In `apache2.conf` I added:

```
<Location /folder1/folder2>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Location>

<FilesMatch /folder3/file1>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The first part works partially correct: When I access any file from http://x.x.x.x/folder1/folder2/ (either file or a folder) I am getting:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access ... on this server.
```

But when I am accessing something like: http://x.x.x.x/nonExistingFolder/ I am getting `Not Found` and therefore it looks like I am leaking information that something in folder1/folder2/ exist and this something is important. Is there a way to show there also not found.

Another problem is that I can still access `/folder3/file1` What am I doing wrong with FilesMatch? I am on apache `2.4.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite in the /folder1 directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /folder1
RewriteRule   ^$ - [R=404,L]
```